How do I compare two runs by metric-over-time, not just a single metric value?
I have my MLflow runs set up to log train/val loss regularly, like this:
mlflow.log_metric("train/loss", train_loss, step=iter_num)

In the web view I can click "model metrics" and see a plot of loss by step. But when I try to compare the loss curve between two runs by selecting them and clicking "compare", I can't find any visualization that shows more than a single value for the loss (the loss from the last step logged, I think).
Is there a way to see the same kind of plot I get in "model metrics" but comparing two runs? Am I using the API wrong?

use mlflow.create_experiment() to make a new experiment

for two different runs, run using mlflow.start_run()

log loss each step/epoch by calling mlflow.log_metric(..., step=X)

in web UI, check the two runs and click compare
-> all but the loss value form the final step seems to have disappeared


